# How can I add several products to a Drupal Commerce cart by

Tags: commerce

I wish to use Drupal Commerce to take bookings on my hotel booking site, all of the hotel detail is provided by Laterooms via XML (using Feeds). Obviously hotel availability changes all the time so I can't (and wouldn't want to) bulk download and process all availability data, so this needs to happen when the site user requests it.

So far, so good, that's working fine, and I can book individual nights accommodation easily enough.

I would like to combine several nights stay into a single product (or group of products) so when a customer requests a two, three or more nights at a particular hotel they can do that with one click and have the cart show the nights bundled into one order line.

Thanks,

Chris